# Decrease padding between two row in Grid semantic ui react

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using grid in semantic ui react and you are able to see in picture name and mob have padding i want to decrease these padding between them

[image: Picture below]

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const GridExampleRows = () => (
  <Grid columns={2}>
    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>Name</span>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>: Arman</span>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>

    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>Mob</span>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>: 0987654321</span>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
  </Grid>
)

export default GridExampleRows
```

Comment: what is your desired outcome? how much less padding do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try define inline styles with reduced padding, and apply to `Grid.Row`.

It seems that `Image` is also included as `import` but not used in posted example, so the styles value would possibly need to be further adjusted to be also fitting for `Image`.

Quick basic example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kt2wk7?file=src/App.js)

```
//  Set top and bottom padding 3px, left and right 0px
const rowStyle = { padding: "3px 0px" };

const GridExampleRows = () => (
  <Grid columns={2}>
    <Grid.Row style={rowStyle}>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>Name</span>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>: Arman</span>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>

    <Grid.Row style={rowStyle}>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>Mob</span>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <span>: 0987654321</span>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
  </Grid>
);

export default GridExampleRows;
```